# ModX Evolution: pass variable from url to form text field on page load

Tags: forms, url, parameters, modx

I need to pass string from url:

```
../page.html?code=123456
```

to a form (eform snippet in modx) 
just once is page loaded (link with url and parameter)
Thanks for answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:
1. create a new snippet called GetCode

```
<?php
if( !function_exists('eformGetCode') ) {
function eformGetCode(&$fields,&$templates){
global $modx;
$code = strip_tags($_GET['codeID']);
$templates['tpl']=str_replace('[+display_code+]',$code,$templates['tpl']);
return true; } }
return '';
?>
```

2. Add eform call (and snippet) on webpage:

```
[!GetCode!]
[!eForm? ... ... &eFormOnBeforeFormParse=`eformGetCode` !]
```

3. In eform chunk with form code add line:

```
<input name="code" id="code" value="[+display_code+]" eform="::1:" type="text"/>
```

5. Now when you put parametr in url like:

```
..../page.html?code=123456
```

this should appear in form.

Answer (score 0):

you would do this exactly like you would in php..

```
$myVar = $_GET['code'];
```

If you are having issues, take a peek in the modx error logs...

-sean

Comment: Well not really a php programmer, can you be more specific?

Comment: Not really, that's about as simple as it gets, what you are going to need to do is pass php variables back and forth between the form snippet & the presentation chunk, that is going to require some programming chops. This is also well documented on the modx site itself.  http://rtfm.modx.com

Answer (score 0):

Solution by KudyKam is better than official solution in MODX docs, in which they use a database. http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/Populate_eform_with_dynamic_data